# Somar valores float de uma Table

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando somar o valor dos campos de uma table, porém não está dando certo, com parseInt funciona, só que tem valores que não vão ser inteiros, então coloquei como float, mas ele não realiza a soma:

```
let result = 0;
let columns = $("#tablepesquisaprodutos tr td:nth-child(" + 5 + ")");

columns.each(i => {
    result += parseFloat($(columns[i]).html());
});
$("#DescontoP").val(result);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para o seu código a diferença foi apenas o `toFixed` na exibição, segundo [essa resposta do soen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12511102/4551469):

```
let result = 0;
let columns = $("#tablepesquisaprodutos tr td:nth-child(" + 5 + ")");

columns.each(i => {
    result = parseFloat(result ) + parseFloat($(columns[i]).html());
});
$("#DescontoP").val(result.toFixed(2));
```